# getting black screen while trying to record dockerized lxde using ffmpeg

Tags: docker, opengl, ffmpeg

I have created a docker image that has LXDE and TightVNCServer.

```
# Pull base image.
FROM ubuntu

# Install LXDE and VNC server.
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y xvfb
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y lxde-core lxterminal tightvncserver
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN touch /root/.Xresources
RUN touch /root/.Xauthority
COPY xstartup /root/.vnc/xstartup
RUN chmod +x /root/.vnc/xstartup
#Install Node.js & npm

# Define working directory.
WORKDIR /data

COPY * /data

RUN apt-get install -y ffmpeg
```

I am running this container using this command:

```
docker run -it --rm -v /data:/data -p 5901:5901 -e USER=root ubuntudsktp  bash -c "vncserver :1 -geometry 1280x800 -depth 24 && tail -F /root/.vnc/*.log"
```

I am logging into this container using VNC and running this command to record the whole screen:

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -i :1.0 output.webm
```

After the recording was over, I opened the video and I could see that the video is completely blank(black screen).

this is also my input when i try to run `glxinfo`:

```
# glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer"
Error: unable to open display
```

I have also tried to run it using:

```
DISPLAY=:1 ffmpeg -f x11grab -i :1.0 output.webm
```

And the results are the same.

What I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment to ask for clarification due to my low reputation score, I'll try helping with a "guessing what you try to accomplish" answer.
It's not clear to me why are you trying to record from X11, I'll try guessing you want to record some desktop or app session into a file, for demo purposes, for instance.

Looking at what you try to do in the Dockerfile, there is a great tool that does that, with the added benefit of letting you choose among several X11 servers (Xorg, Xpra, Xephyr...) and also several Desktop Environments (LXDE, FVWM, Gnome...).
The biggest advantage of using it is that it takes care of lots of the plumbing, container attaching/mounting and images and it also provides lots of choices and combinations for you to try. For instance, there's some great X server such as Xpra, which serves a stream which might be what you're after with your ffmpeg usage. It also features lots of docs which will be useful when dealing with running GUI apps in Docker, which can be painful.

Check the tool here: https://github.com/mviereck/x11docker